# Confused with my monitor Picture Modes

Tags: color-management, color-correction, color-spaces, display-calibration, monitors

I've recently bought my first "Designer Monitor", Benq PD2500Q (yeah I know it's probably still shit for professionals, but for me it's the first 'better' monitor). I'm very impressed by it in overall, although it has a bit of ips glow when looking from very short distance, but that's not the point of my question.

What I'm confused about is "Picture Modes" and which one should I choose for photo editing, video editing, "casual" using etc. This monitor offers (among others) Standard, sRGB and Rec.709 Modes. It has 100% sRGB and Rec.709 coverage, and it's factory calibrated (my unit deltaE is 1.0372).

My observations about these factory modes:

-sRGB - the lightest (most detailed) shadows out of those 3

-Standard - more vibrant colors than sRGB mode, but darker shadows - less detailed darker areas

-Rec.709 - even darker shadows than Standard mode, a lot of information missing in darker areas (appear as just black), colors as vibrant as in Standard mode - my favorite one for watching movies, (previous two have visible tonal transitions in shadows).

Should I use sRGB mode for photo editing and Rec.709 for video editing? Or should I create my own "User" mode?

Are all of these modes (sRGB, Standard, Rec.709) factory calibrated? If I create my own User mode, will the factory calibration affect it too? User mode with the same settings as Standard mode looks kinda the same.

Thank you guys in advance, I'm starting in photography and need some guidance

Cheers

Comment: What [computer] display profiles were supplied by the manufacturer? I have half an answer below - can't do the rest of it without knowing that information.

Comment: Hey, thank you for response, I don't think I've received any files - I just have Benq PD2500Q.icm profile set in Color Management Windows Settings. I just plugged in monitor, I think drivers were automatically installed and thats all. It came with a paper with my unit calibration details (Measurement Conditions - color temperature, gamma curve, color gamut - sRGB, input signal, device; deltaE result, and color gamut and gamma graphs). More about Benq Factory Calibration here:
https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/why-factory-calibrated-monitor.html

Comment: Benq seem to have some proprietary system for colour management, with which I have no experience - see if this helps https://www.benq.com/en-us/monitor/software/display-pilot.html

Comment: Yup I installed it just as I plugged my monitor in, it's just a way to switch monitor settings from within operating system, without touching buttons on casing

Answer (score 2):

Colour profiling is a mystery wrapped in an enigma. A quagmire waiting for you as you climb out of the crocodile-infested river…

All those pretty pictures the display offers you are great - but not if the computer doesn't know what the display is set to.

If your display came with a set of profiles, one for each standard, then that would be a start. Set the computer's display profile to the same option as you set the screen to.

If it doesn't, then all you have are half a dozen different ways of not knowing whether the colours are accurate or not.

As it claims to be 'factory calibrated' then they should have given you an individual profile for that calibration, otherwise it was just 'advertising speak', not worth the paper it wasn't printed on.

[...More, after we know what profiles we have to work from…]
. . . probably followed by a brief lecture on hardware calibration. . . ;)

After comments - you'll be best to set it to sRGB full-time. Rec709 is similar to sRGB but designed for video & has a different gamma curve. I don't edit much video, but when I do, I keep my calibration the same. if I play back from my TV, it looks as it should. However, all my hardware, including the TV, is hardware calibrated, so I expect the picture to be the same on all displays in the building.

Set to sRGB basically you have a 'best guess'. As the manufacturer provides no profiles, that's as close as you can get by using presets alone.

If you were to invest in a hardware colorimeter, then you could get closer to accurate, but this is an investment. On Windows, I think the cheap Huey Pro still works [it won't run on Mac any more]. Better would be an X-Rite ColorMunki, or i1 Display Pro or a Spyder 5. The downside is those last two will cost about the same as your display - but it's a buy once, use forever product. All the screens in the house & even iPhones & TVs if you have the right software.

Comment: As a note, many of the camera rental places one can find online will rent display calibration equipment for considerably less than the purchase price.